# App cannot receive multicast packets on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, multicast

I have a CentOS 7.2 machine that is a VMware guest. I am subscribing to a multicast group and seeing all the multicast I'd expect, but my app is not seeing the contents of the stream. strace shows that it is waiting on a select() system call. What am I forgetting?

Here's what I've done:

- Started a multicast sender on a remote host.
- Built a CentOS 7.2 guest on a VMware host.
- I stop and disable firewalld, and `yum erase filewalld` on the guest. `iptables -L` shows:

-

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

- I run : `socat UDP4-RECVFROM:65000,ip-add-membership=239.31.82.10:10.0.54.210,fork STDOUT`
- I see no output from the command.
- `netstat -gn` shows that it is subscribed to the multicast group.
- selinux is disabled, in `/etc/selinux/config` I see: `SELINUX=disabled`. Yes, I have rebooted since that setting. Also I see: `SELinux status:                 disabled` from `sestatus`
- `tcpdump -n -nn -i eth0 host 239.31.82.10` shows packets hitting the interface from that IP, destined to the UDP port 65000.
- Another host subscribed to the same multicast group sees data.
- I build another VM guest, this time using CentOS 6.4, and it works fine. I see regular output from my multicast sender.
- I build another VM guest, again using CentOS 7.2, and it works fine. This time I use a minimal install, however.

My issue *looks* like the firewall is blocking the packets, but as shown there is no firewall enabled.

The one significant difference between my not-working host and my working host is that the not-working host has two interfaces configured on it. But again, I am showing it as subscribed to the multicast group and I am showing packets hitting the interface. As well, I have shut down the second interface but that has not helped.

Thanks.

Comment: try to disable selinux to test if it is the culprit

Comment: Good catch. Forgot to mention that it's disabled. I've edited my text.

Answer (score 3):

AGH! Famous words,

> The one significant difference between my not-working host and my working host is ...

...for therein lie dragons!

AGH! Famous assumptions,

> ...But...

...for therein lies the root of all confusion!

The problem is Linux' networking reverse path filtering. The problem is that the packets are coming in on an interface and the routing table sees that the sending host's from address should come/go through the other interface (on which lies the default router). Therefore, the kernel was dropping the packets and not sending them to my app.

The IGMP reports were sent because, well, I told socat which interface I should use. And the routers and switches dutifully set up the multicast to go exactly where I told it to go. Ultimately, it was the kernel which was not happy.

The cheap and sleazy fix is to use sysctl to change `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter` from `1` to `0`, but that could cause unforeseen consequences if you're not careful (packets out of order, receiving packets that you don't want, packets coming in on the wrong interface). Better to make sure the routing table reflects the reality of what you're trying to do. So the other fix is to set `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-iface` so that there's a source or network route in it specifically for the multicast sender ip on that particular iface (ie, `eth1` or what have you).

Comment: This is interesting to explain the problem, but the modification proposed in this answer was not enough. What actually solved that routing table problem was this: [What does this linux command mean "route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 eth0" - Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/359536/what-does-this-linux-command-mean-route-add-net-224-0-0-0-netmask-240-0-0-0-et/359539)